# Swift: Date() to UTC global time string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Hi I want to convert `Date()` into string by following this format exactly `2020-07-29T05:27:04.000Z`.

**Tried1:**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                  
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    let string = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    
    print("String: \(string)")
```

**Output 1:** `2020-08-06T10:14:25.890Z`

**Tried2:**

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
    let string =  formatter.string(from: Date())
    
    print("String: \(string)")
```

**Output2:** `2020-08-06T10:17:33.508Z`

But I want to get string that exactly matches to `2020-07-29T05:27:04.000Z` this format. Please help me to find out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace SSS with 000

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000XXXXX"
```